# Android facebook-sdk how to post to wall using dialog?

Tags: android, facebook

I have Facebook button on my Activity, and i want to post my message on wall on click.
OnCreate i am initializing

```
facebookClient = new Facebook(KEY);
```

And on key pressed i am trying to launch dialog

```
 facebookClient.dialog(MyActivity.this, "feed", new Facebook.DialogListener() {
```

Authorization page is lunched. After i try to login, i see empty TextBox where i can enter message and after one second application quits. 
What is the problem? How i can preset text in this TextBox? 
It is good way to use it or i need to do separate activity for facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have followed the steps outlined here. It seems as if you may have missed a step.

Make sure you have registered the app with facebook

And requested the correct permission in your code to post on a users wall.

[Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#register)

Comment: no, i followed all steps. Register app on face book, generated key and entered there and received app ID